# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext change image size

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing

I am making drawing application where i need to draw image.

But when i try to to that image size is change. i want the same size of image after draw.

Here is my code

```
  NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.size));
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.size));
```

O/p

```
    2014-08-24 15:11:14.511 Demo[4877:60b] {877, 1136}
2014-08-24 15:11:15.533 Demo[4877:60b] {320, 460}
```

**How can take image quality same as before Here image is scale down**

Comment: Show your drawing code

Comment: same problem here, did u solve it?

Comment: Same problem here too..

Answer (score 0):

//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)

```
    //Use this:


    let hasAlpha = true
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    let size = (size of your canvas / imageview)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale) //use this

    //Instead of this:

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size) //dont use this
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to add some more details explaining about the code.